# Transpose rows to columns while preserving index as it is

Tags: pandas, indexing, stack, transpose

I have the dataset of the following structure:

```
data = {'Var_name': ['GDP', 'FX', 'Inf'], '2000': [4, 5, 6], '2001': [7, 8, 9], '2002': [10, 11, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['Country_1', 'Country_1', 'Country_1'])

          Var_name     2000  2001   2002
Country_1   GDP         4     7      10
Country_1   FX          5     8      11
Country_1   Inf         6     9      12
```

I want to transpose it to the following format:

```
            Year    GDP FX  Inf
Country_1   2000    4   5   6
Country_1   2001    7   8   9
Country_1   2002    10  11  12
```

Thank for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df = (df.set_index('Var_name', append=True)
        .stack(0)
        .unstack(1)
        .rename_axis(index=(None, 'Year'), columns=None)
        .reset_index(level=1))
print (df)
           Year  FX  GDP  Inf
Country_1  2000   5    4    6
Country_1  2001   8    7    9
Country_1  2002  11   10   12
```

EDIT: Problem is duplicated `Var_name` with `Country` index values like:

```
data = {'Var_name': ['GDP', 'GDP', 'Inf'], '2000': [4, 5, 6], '2001': [7, 8, 9], '2002': [10, 11, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['Country_1', 'Country_1', 'Country_1'])
print (df)
          Var_name  2000  2001  2002
Country_1      GDP     4     7    10 <- duplicate row
Country_1      GDP     5     8    11 <- duplicate row
Country_1      Inf     6     9    12
```

So is necessary use some aggregation function like `mean`, `sum`:

```
df = (df.set_index('Var_name', append=True)
        .stack(0)
        .groupby(level=[0,1,2])
        .mean()
        .unstack(1)
        .rename_axis(index=(None, 'Year'), columns=None)
        .reset_index(level=1)
        )
print (df)
           Year   GDP   Inf
Country_1  2000   4.5   6.0
Country_1  2001   7.5   9.0
Country_1  2002  10.5  12.0
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. So I run the proposed answer with step by step and noticed that it is failing in `unstuck(1)` part. It shows the following error: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`.

Comment: @HumoyunUsmanaliyev - added soluton for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .pivot_table

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Country_1'], columns='Var_name', values='Year',aggfunc='first')
```

Comment: Yeah thanks! I could come up with the same solution actually just now. Like so:  `dfff = pd.pivot_table(df_m, index=['iso3_o'], columns=['Indicator Name'])\
         .stack(0)`;         
`dfff.index = dfff.index.rename(['iso3_o','year'])`;
`dfff.columns.name = None`